# Colab pro never give me more than 16 gb of gpu memory

Tags: google-colaboratory

[image]

[image]

I have been using colab pro for a month, but it only has 16gb when using it. On the upper right, it says it has 25gb, but it only has 16 GB.

Answer (score 2):

You are viewing GPU memory. System memory is reported by running a cell with the following:

```
!cat /proc/meminfo
```

Answer (score 1):

The RAM in the upper right corner refers to the instance's memory capacity (which is 25.51GB in your case), not your GPU memory.

To view your GPU memory run the following command in a cell: `!nvidia-smi`

Comment: it says it can give me a double ram, and it is just a lie.

Comment: It can give you up to 25GB of Ram even without the pro plan. In that case, you are assigned more Ram only when you are consuming memory close to the limit.